# Determining casting of an object

Tags: c#, .net, casting, object

I have the code below

```
RssFeedReader rss = (RssFeedReader)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
```

My problem is only at run time do I know if 'this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart' is of type RssFeedReader or of type 'RssCountry'

How would I check the object type and cast it appropriatley?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if (this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart is RssFeedReader)
    //...
```

To check if it is of a certain type. Alternatively, you can use 'as' to use it as a type, and it will be null if it was not of that type.

```
RssFeedReader reader = this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart as RssFeedReader;
if (reader != null)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could say

```
RssFeedReader rss;
rss = this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart as RssFeedReader;
if(rss != null) {
    // an RssFeedReader
}

RssCountry rc;
rc = this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart as RssCountry;
if(rc != null) {
    // an RssCountry
}
```

or

```
if(this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart is RssFeedReader) {
    // an RssFeedReader
    RssFeedReader rss = (RssFeedReader)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
}

if(this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart is RssCountry) {
    // an RssCountry
    RssCountry rc = (RssCountry)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
}
```

But, be warned. Almost any time that you are basing your logic on the type is a bad design smell!

Comment: Thanks i decided to create a seperate class - as it smelt bad